# Scroll by mouse drag

Tags: delphi-xe

For some reason, user is having problem using the vertical and horizontal scroll bars in TTreeView. They want to scroll by drag(simulate finger on touchscreen). I'm not sure where to start with this one.

I know how to implement drag and drop in TTreeView and I also know how to simulate scrolls when a key is pressed.

**EDIT**

I have a ttreeview that has 200 rows, vertical and horizontal bars are visible.  I want to achieve that when I click on a **white space inside the treeview** and drag it upwards to see other rows it should automatically scroll.

I'm not sure where to start coding. Sadly, TTreeView.OnStartDrag will only fire if you selected a node and drag it. I tried checking OnMouseMove but **Mouse.IsDragging** is always false.

Comment: Scrolling using a scrollbar and dragging it works fine in TTreeView. You don't have to write any code to make it work, so your question is unclear and needs much more information.

Comment: i'm editing my question

Answer (score 0):

The solution I made is via-threading. I created a thread that will check VK_LBUTTON key state and mouse position every 50 milliseconds. Here is the thread :

```
TDragThread = class(TThread)
  private
    fLogMessage : string;
    fX,
    fY : Integer;

    procedure DoWork;
    procedure LogMessage;
    procedure DoScroll;

  protected
    procedure Execute; override;

  public
    IsDragging : Boolean;
    constructor Create; reintroduce;
  end;

{ TDragThread }

constructor TDragThread.Create;
begin
  inherited Create(True);
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
  IsDragging := False;
end;

procedure TDragThread.DoScroll;
var
  i : Integer;
begin

  // horizontal scroll
  if fX > 0 then
  begin
    SendMessage(Form1.tv1.Handle, WM_HSCROLL, SB_LINELEFT, 0);
  end
  else if fX < 0 then
  begin
    SendMessage(Form1.tv1.Handle, WM_HSCROLL, SB_LINERIGHT, 0);
  end;

  // vertical
  if fY > 0 then
  begin
    SendMessage(Form1.tv1.Handle, WM_VSCROLL, SB_LINEUP, 0);
  end
  else if fY < 0 then
  begin
    SendMessage(Form1.tv1.Handle, WM_VSCROLL, SB_LINEDOWN, 0);
  end;
end;

procedure TDragThread.DoWork;
var
  nTemp : SmallInt;
  point : TPoint;
  oldPoint : TPoint;
  downCount : Integer;
begin
  downCount := 0;
  while not Terminated do
  begin

    if IsDragging then
    begin

      nTemp := GetKeyState(VK_LBUTTON);
      point := Mouse.CursorPos;
      if nTemp < 0 then
      begin
        downCount := downCount + 1;
        fLogMessage := 'MOUSE DOWN- X:' + IntToStr(point.X) + ' Y:' + IntToStr(point.Y);
        Synchronize(LogMessage);

        if downCount > 1 then
        begin
          fX := (point.X - oldPoint.X) div 20;
          fY := (point.Y - oldPoint.Y) div 10;

          if (fX <> 0) or (fY <> 0) then
          begin
            Synchronize(DoScroll);
          end;

          fLogMessage := 'fX:' + IntToStr(fX) + ' fY:' + IntToStr(fY);
          Synchronize(LogMessage);
        end;
        oldPoint := point;

      end
      else
      begin
        if downCount > 2 then
        begin
          fLogMessage := 'DO SCROLL';
          Synchronize(LogMessage);
        end;

        fLogMessage := 'MOUSE UP';
        Synchronize(LogMessage);
        downCount := 0;
        IsDragging := False;
      end;
    end;

    Sleep(50);
  end;
end;

procedure TDragThread.Execute;
begin
  inherited;
  CoInitialize(nil);
  try

    DoWork;

  finally
    CoUninitialize;
  end;

end;

procedure TDragThread.LogMessage;
begin
  Form1.mmo1.Lines.Add(fLogMessage);
end;
```

The instance of the thread will start when you create the form :

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin    
  fDragThread := TDragThread.Create;
  fDragThread.Start;
end;
```

Then you need to set the public variable IsDragging to true when a mouse down is detected in the TTreeView :

```
procedure TForm1.tv1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if fDragThread = nil then
  begin
    Exit;
  end;

  fDragThread.IsDragging := True;
end;
```

The dragging experience is not that smooth, but now user can drag the tree content without using the horizontal and vertical scrollbars.